# A Batarang issue when build MEANJS demo (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToggleElement' of null)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meanjs, batarang

I'm trying to use AngularJS Batarang when lean to build a MEANJS App.

Here is the tutorial URL: http://www.bossable.com/656/mean-stack-mongodb-angular-scope/

What I find is my "Scopes" tab's presentation is different from the tutorial video and has an error printed.

My result of Batarang Plugin.

[image]

A result from the tutorial.

[image]

I don't know if it's because the different version of Batarang, or the error printed.

Comment: Batarang is not longer supported, and the latest released versions don't even work with the more current releases of Angular.

Comment: The latest version of Batarang seemed to stop working awhile ago - check out this video for instructions on setting up an earlier version:
http://www.bossable.com/1157/angularjs-batarang-in-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Your error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToggleElement' of null)" is not related to Batarang, it's actually from angular-ui. It appears when you select an option from a picklist. I believe it has been fixed in the most recent version.

Here are some quick steps to show you how to remove your existing version of AngularJS Batarang, and how to install a ‘working’ version.

1. Download Batarang from the releases page on GitHub (https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/releases)
2. Extract the downloaded file
3. Open a Chrome tab and navigate to to chrome://extensions/
4. Find, disable or remove any existing versions of the extension that are currently installed
5. On the top right, the checkbox for “Developer mode” should be checked
6. Click “Load unpacked extension…”
7. Select the directory where you extracted the extension

Checkout the video here: http://www.bossable.com/1157/angularjs-batarang-in-chrome/